# Cannot access ACF field in php code

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to set a custom field `featured_image` with ACF and can't access it within my php code. First are screenshots of confirming adding the field to the latest post, then after is the php code.

I'm very new to WordPress so I'm expecting this to be a trivial misunderstanding.

I've run `var_dump( get_post_meta(get_the_ID()) );` which doesn't show the existence of the 'featured_image' field. I've also created a `text` custom field, which also doesn't show up.

[image: ACF field setup]

[image: Setting field value on post]

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2&posts_per_page=3' );
  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
      // some variable code
?>

    <div class="section-info background3">
      <div class="section-details">
        // some irrelevant html

        <?php

          $image = get_field('featured_image');
          var_dump( $image );
          echo $image;

          $featured_image = the_field('featured_image');
          var_dump( $featured_image );

          $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

          if( $image ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Which outputs

`bool(false)` for `var_dump( $image );`

`NULL` for           `var_dump( $featured_image );`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First strategy I'd go for in this case is to confirm that the data is present at the DB level.

Run a query against your DB:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = YOUR_POST_ID AND `meta_key` LIKE '%featured_image%'
```

If you can confirm that the data's there, then the next thing to do is ensure that you're passing the right post_id to get_field.

Because you're creating a custom `WP_Query`, and `get_field` usually infers ID from the global `$post` var, there's always potential for confusion. [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) optionally takes a second `$post_id` parameter.

If you can dump the contents of `get_the_ID()` inside your custom loop, and confirm that it matches the post whose `featured_image` field has the data, then send it along in the form of

```
<?php 

$my_query = new WP_Query('cat=2&posts_per_page=3');

while ($my_query->have_posts() ) :
    $my_query->the_post();
    var_dump(get_the_ID()); // <-- this should match the ID of the post w/ the featured_image
    $image = get_field('featured_image', get_the_ID());
    var_dump($image);
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); // always good practice to reset the globals after a custom q!
```

Comment: Your SQL query helped me find the issue. I had confirmed that 'featured_image' was in the DB, but didn't check that it connected to the correct post.


Once I found out the post # was different, I realised I was using the wrong category (each post in category 2 has a verrrrrry similar post in category 4). Once I changed the category, I could then fetch the field.


Thanks :)

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to hear it, Simon. :)